# How to remove the items left margin in a WPF ListView?

Tags: wpf, listviewitem

I have created a very simple ListView in WPF.

I would like to remove the left spacing that is present for each item (represented by the red arrows in my screenshot).

How can I do it?

[image: The red arrows represent the spacing I'd like to eliminate]

```
    <ListView>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Company" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListViewItem Content="A" />
        <ListViewItem Content="B" />
        <ListViewItem Content="C" />
    </ListView>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `ListViewItem.Margin` to `-6,0` to compensate the Margin from the GridView.

[image]

You can find that with [SnoopWpf](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf)

```xml
<ListView>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Company" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    <ListViewItem Content="A" Margin="-6,0" />
    <ListViewItem Content="B" Margin="-6,0" />
    <ListViewItem Content="C" Margin="-6,0" />
</ListView>
```